# File Writing optimizations - FileOutputStream vs Writers

Tags: java

I'm using a simple logger on a server, which uses a method that looks like this:

```
@Override
public synchronized void write(String logtag, String reason, int severity) {

    long logtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String message = "";

    switch (severity) {
        case DEBUG:
            if (!debug) return;
            message = "[" + logtime + "] {DEBUG} " + logtag + "% " + reason + "\n$";
            break;
        case INFO:
            message = "[" + logtime + "] {INFO} " + logtag + "% " + reason + "\n$";
            break;
        case ERROR:
            message = "[" + logtime + "] {ERROR} " + logtag + "% " + reason + "\n$";
            break;
        case FATAL:
            message = "[" + logtime + "] {FATAL} " + logtag + "% " + reason + "\n$";
           break;
        case EXCEPTION:
            message = "[" + logtime + "] {EXCEPTION} " + logtag + "% " + reason + "\n$";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Anthrazit error! Invalid severity: " + severity;
    } 

    try {
        out.write(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorOnInit(e);
    }

    if (exitOnFatal && severity == FATAL) {
        System.err.println("Anthrazit exit on fatal: " + message + ". Please check the logs.");
        close();
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

After doing some research I found some classes designed to to this, like `PrintWriter` and others. Is there any performance difference between my approach and the `PrintWriter`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/FileOutputStream.html):

> `FileOutputStream` is meant for writing streams of raw bytes such as image data. For writing streams of characters, consider using [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/FileWriter.html).

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371154/outputstreamwriter-vs-filewriter

You could also use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of doing manually a string concatenation.

Also, the whole method is sychronized. The message probably does not need to be constructed in the sychronized block. Only concrete write to the Stream/File should be sychronized:

```
long logtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
// construct string etc

sychronized(this){
    out.write(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

You could also try to read the code of "real" logging frameworks to get ideas how they work.

Comment: Is there any negative side effects of using a FileOutputStream? I think there is not. I also now buffered the output of the FileOutputStream for better performance.

Comment: @Gala: Well since the FileWriter API is designed for String handling, it provides more convienient methods and probably also has less pitfalls.

Comment: I'll stick with the FileOutputStream.

Comment: The advantage of writers are that you specify the charset at the constructor, instead of at every call